# USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 - Which is best for creating recovery disc of Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, usb-flash-drive, operating-systems, partition-recovery

Please correct me if I'm asking nonsense!

I just bought a new laptop 'HP 15-AC053TX 15.6-inch Laptop (Core i7-5500U/8GB/1TB/Win 8.1/2GB Graphics), Turbo Silver' and I would like to prepare a recovery drive of Windows 8.1 using a flash drive (pen drive). The OS is Windows 8.1. But I'm in a dilemma what type to choose, I mean USB 3.0(which is more faster, I'm not sure about the durability and its stability) OR USB 2.0(which has got much user acceptance, stability and durability but yes with lesser speed).

Please share the pros and cons of both in the given context of creating a recovery disc using a flash drive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter. As you'll probably never need use it, go for the most cost effective option. If you ever do need to use it, it'll just take a bit longer if it's USB 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

USB 3.0 is backwards compatible and the main difference between 2.0 is improved transfer speeds. The data structure is the same in 2.0 / 3.0. USB 3 has been out for a pretty long while already too and I'm not aware of any drawbacks aside from compatibility with old hardware.

Do you have a flash drive in USB 3.0 as well? A port alone will not be enough for you to get the USB 3.0 speed, you need both port and a device that support it

Answer (score 1):

Always pick an USB 3.0 device with [USB Attached SCSI (UASP) support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI). For my external SSD I get over 400MB write/read speed. So this is the best choice. With USB 2.0 you only get 40MB/s and doing a large backup would take much, longer.

If you care about data integrity, transfer the backup image over [TCPIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP) to a NAS because TCP checks if the data packages are transferred correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason not to use a USB 3.0 device if you have one. It will work just as well in a USB 2.0 host, but as the point is to recover your own device (whuich presumably has a USB 3.0 port) then this is a moot point.

The cost difference nowadays is minimal, but then so is the potential for time saved during a recovery.